# Date-labels missing in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In the chart described in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BbZq7/), the date-labels on the x axis are missing. Can anyone tell me why that is? The code in the fiddle is listed below:

```
$(function () {
        var counts = [[635172879695710000, 383], [635172882696280000, 271], [635172885696780000, 274]],
        averages = [[635172879695710000, 288774], [635172882696280000, 85592], [635172885696780000, 79455]],
        ranges = [[635172879695710000, 12, 2760740], [635172882696280000, 12, 2761263], [635172885696780000, 12, 2761265]];

        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Testing!'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },
            yAxis: [{
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value}B',
                        style: {
                            color: '#89A54E'
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Size',
                        style: {
                            color: '#89A54E'
                        }
                    },
                    min: 0
                }, {
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value}M',
                        style: {
                            color: '#4572A7'
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Messages',
                        style: {
                            color: '#4572A7'
                        }
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    opposite: false
                }],
            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },
            series: [{
                    name: 'Line',
                    type: 'spline',
                    data: averages,
                    color: '#89A54E',
                    zIndex: 1,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'Area',
                    data: ranges,
                    type: 'areasplinerange',
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    linkedTo: ':previous',
                    color: '#89A54E',
                    fillOpacity: 0.3,
                    zIndex: 0
                }, {
                    name: 'Count',
                    data: counts,
                    type: 'spline',
                    zIndex: 2,
                    color: '#4572A7',
                    yAxis: 1,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High charts is *unable to parse the `datetime` that you have given.*

Check console for the following **`error`**

> Cannot call method 'substr' of undefined

Your `dateTime` seems to be **`micromilliseconds`**, which is not valid

```
635172879695710000
635172882696280000
635172885696780000
```

Try to change the format to milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

check the timestamp they are invalid.

```
[timestamp, value]
```

updated your timestamps and got it working http://jsfiddle.net/BbZq7/7/